# Cannot create a simple Azure AKS with Terraform anymore

Tags: terraform, azure-aks

I am not able to create a Azure Kubernetes Service using the following code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.96.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks-rg" {
  name     = "aks-rg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks-1" {
  name                = "aks-1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks-rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "aks1"
  
  default_node_pool {
    name       = "nodepool1"
    node_count = 3
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Test"
  }
}
```

The following error occurs:

```
│ Error: creating Cluster: (Managed Cluster Name "aks-1" / Resource Group "aks-rg"): 
containerservice.ManagedClustersClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending 
request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="RequestDisallowedByPolicy" Message=
"Provisioning of resource(s) for container service aks-1 in resource group aks-rg failed. Message: Resource 
'aks-nodepool1-58423643-vmss' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers: 
'[{\"policyAssignment\":{\"name\":\"Enforce automatic OS upgrade with app health checks
```

What am I doing wrong?
Do I need to manually create a VMSS first?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Enforce automatic OS upgrade with app health checks* is a [built-in policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/built-in-policies) enforced on your subscription / resource group that denies creating a VMSS without automatic OS upgrade enabled.

```
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets"
      },
      {
        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachineScaleSets/upgradePolicy.automaticOSUpgradePolicy.enableAutomaticOSUpgrade",
        "notEquals": "True"
      },
      {
        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachineScaleSets/upgradePolicy.automaticOSUpgrade",
        "notEquals": "True"
      }
    ]
  },
```

I've seen others raising [same problem](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/create-aks-cluster-with-node-pool-vmss-setting-automatic-os-upgrade-enabled/16653) for azurerm provider. But it can't be fixed at provider level, as just there is no such param when adding a node pool to AKS (eg. looking though options of [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks/nodepool?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-nodepool-add)).

You can only ask your admins to disable the policy or add an [exemption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/exemption-structure) for you.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it seems to be the only option at the moment. It works.